# Pipenv not resolving dependencies correctly with two sources listed

Tags: python, pipenv

I've got a Pipfile with two sources declared: one source is the global, public PyPI, while the other is a small local repository which hosts some private packages, but doesn't mirror PyPI itself. I've got this set up as follows:

```
[[source]]
url = "http://my.private.repo.example.com/pypi/simple"
verify_ssl = false
name = "private"

[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

This being in place, I use both mirrors to source packages:

```
[packages]
requests = "*"
some_private_package = {version="*", index="private"}
```

My issue is that this results in a failure to resolve some dependencies. Let's say that `some_private_package` depends on `Flask` -- which is available from public PyPI, but isn't hosted on the private repo; building `some_private_package` fail because `Flask` can't be found on the private repo, and no attemps are made to scan PyPI for it.

Is there any way to get Pipenv to search for dependencies on both available sources?

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to how `some_private_package` declares *its* dependencies.

Comment: They're jut declared as simple versioned dependencies in `some_private_package`'s `setup.py` `install_requires`; is there a more canonical way of doing this with Pipenv, short of converting every internal dependency into a Pipenv project?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a latent answer to this: apparently the private host doesn't correctly handle a wildcard version specifier, preferring either a bare package name or a valid version specifier instead.

Explicitly pinning all packages seems to be the way to go when working with some of the self-hosted PyPI servers.